# set scroll view for edit text above the list view android

Tags: android

i hava a edit text and a submitt button for displaying output in list view but when i write something in edit text then my edit box not appear because of softkey board so i want to set scroll for edit text and submitt button so which i type can be see on edit text.i know i cant set scroll for listview so how to seprate it from list view means how can i use mutiple relative layout for set scrollview only for above content of list

my xml is

Comment: If you want to put whole thing in scrollview then make a scrollview as a parent layout of this relative layout. or else make a part on which your edittext and button laying put it in a scrollview parent layout.

Comment: actually i cant put whole thing in scrollview because i have litview in my layout also and by default listview dont need scroll view..

Comment: and what abt if you put just edittext and button in scrollview?

Comment: then my list view content come in whole screen view

Comment: can u pls modify in my xml  thanks

Comment: pls see my edited question i paste new xml with scroll view tag ..but when i am  using it then my listview contents come in whole view why?

Comment: ok just for try set the properties android:layout_marginTop="150dp" of your list view and use the your first xml file without scrollview. its for just try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try below code in layout

```
 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<-- put your controll here which you want -->
</LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

Comment: pls see my edited question i paste new xml with scroll view tag ..but when i am using it then my listview contents come in whole view why?